# @Parcelize and enum classes - Overload resolution ambiguity

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, parcelable, parcel

I need a clarification about `@Parcelize` annotation in Kotlin. I've declared this enum class:

```kotlin
 @Parcelize
 enum class Source : Parcelable {
    LIST, MAP
 }
```

The class is annotated with `@Parcelize` in order to implement Parcelable interface and it's working fine, however when I try to pass the Parceled class in an intent I have to force a re-casting to Parcelable, otherwise the compiler gives me a "**Overload resolution ambiguity**". error:

> Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
>   @RecentlyNonNull public open fun putExtra(name: String!, value: Parcelable!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent
>   @RecentlyNonNull public open fun putExtra(name: String!, value: Serializable!): Intent! defined in android.content.Intent

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(context, DestinationActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(Constants.RETAIL_DETAILS_CLICK_SOURCE_ID, StoreDetailsClicked.Source
                    .MAP as Parcelable)
```

Why is the compiler giving me this error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because enums are Serializable by default, and when you add Parcelable, it matches both method signatures. You can add an extension function to resolve the ambiguity:

```
fun Intent.putParcelableExtra(key: String, value: Parcelable) {
    putExtra(key, value)
}

intent.putParcelableExtra(
    Constants.RETAIL_DETAILS_CLICK_SOURCE_ID, 
    StoreDetailsClicked.Source.MAP
)
```

Comment: Sure, I see now. An extension function is better than forcing the cast every time! Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I believe removing `Parcelable` and `@Parcelize` is a better solution.